# SQL query for showing the products which sell better, based on how many times an index is found in the table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have customer table which have products and quantity , I need to retrieve those products which sell better in the company.

How would I accomplish this with an SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the common-assumption of a product/order/sales table schema, the following query is constructed. So please either show us your tables or change the query according to your tables.

This will give you the best product:

```
SELECT s.ProductID, ProductName, Max(s.Quantity) as MaxSales
FROM Products p, SalesOrder s
WHERE p.ProductID = s.ProductID
GROUP BY s.ProductID;
```

This will give you 10 best products:

```
SELECT TOP 10 s.ProductID, ProductName, s.Quantity
FROM Products p, SalesOrder s
WHERE p.ProductID = s.ProductID
ORDER BY s.Quantity DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple order by clause should do

```
select products, quantity
from tableName
order by quantity desc
```

If you need only top 5 for example, add "Top 5" between select and products word in above query

Hope that helps